# Custom run task for subproject with arguments from build.sbt?

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a subproject named `oppenheimer` in my project. It's very simple to run this project from the sbt console.

```
[myproject] $ oppenheimer/run
```

I can also pass in a command line argument as such:

```
[myproject] $ oppenheimer/run migrate
[myproject] $ oppenheimer/run clean
```

How can I do this from `build.sbt`? Is it possible to define a task that does this? It would suffice to have something like this:

```
val customMigrate = ...
val customClean = ...
```

And this is so that I could use it elsewhere in the project, like such:

```
(test in Test) <<= (test in Test).dependsOn(customMigrate)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is given in the sbt FAQ section ["How can I create a custom run task, in addition to run?"](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.1/docs/faq.html#how-can-i-create-a-custom-run-task-in-addition-to-run). Basically:

```
lazy val customMigrate = taskKey[Unit]("custom run task")

fullRunTask(customMigrate, Test, "foo.Main", "migrate")
```